# Why I keep getting error in CSS Code in visual studio code?

Tags: css

[VS code error[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXXIx.png)

Guys,

Can anyone advise why I keep seeing those errors in vs code?
Where is my mistake?

regards,
Emilia

Comment: I think is better to show entire your code. Also, your code has some wrongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
.services .box-container {

    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;

    -ms-grid-column: (minmax(32rem, 1fr)) [auto-fit];
    grid-column: (minmax(32rem, 1fr)) [auto-fit];

    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(32rem, ifr));
    
    gap: 1.5rem;

}
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work as I wish :( After I use this code my divs are displayed in a column and i want them in a flex-end. Have no idea why, but when I use my code it displays as I wish and vs keeps showing me the syntax errors. With yours I don't have syntax error, but divs are displayed in the columns instead of in the flex direction

Comment: Update- just worked, so please ignore :)

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept it as answer and upvote.